# Automated build process with NodeJS and databases

Tags: node.js, devops

I have some projects of NodeJS apis using databases. The integration of theses databases is made through an ORM (Sequelize) which requires some setup on the builds. On the very first build, I need to initalize and seed my database (usually with an npm run command). And on every build an npm command might run for database updates (like tables and stuffs). The problem is that some hosts providers allows to host nodejs apps and run automatically the build command and I need a way to run the commands described before on theses cases. Does someone have an idea ?